# API.Session_ID not invalidated after user has logged out from salesforce

Tags: integration, session, .net

I need some help on understanding the salesforce session behavior. I created a web tab pointing to .NET application which is opened within salesforce in Iframe. I'm passing the API.Session_ID value in the web tab's URL which is then used by my .NET app to read/upload data from/in the salesforce org. Screenshot below.

[image]

The strange thing is that when I log out from salesforce the session is non invalidated and my app is able to successfully retrieve data from salesforce. I created a test login page which uses `secur/frontdoor.jsp` and submits the sessionid. I'm logged in with the sessionId no matter the fact the I logged out from salesforce. Any ideas why this is happening? Here's my test login page:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://eu5.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="sid"
      value="sessionIdHere"
      />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" /></form>
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: How are you logging out of Salesforce? I would also expect using the "Logout" option in the UI to invalidate the session. Before you logout, try a SOQL query of AuthSession and compare the results with after you have logged out.

Comment: I'm using the "Logout" option in the UI. Thanks for the idea. I'll give it a try and will share the result.

Comment: I used the logout link in the UI. It invalidated the Session ID and I could no longer use that Session ID with frontdoor.jsp or for API calls.

Comment: @Daniel, do you think it's possible to exist a minimal time interval in which the session is not yet deleted from the sf database server and I'm entering this interval using the frontdoor.jsp to refresh the session? I can't explain this random behaviour otherwise.

Comment: I guess anything is possible. However, it definitely shouldn't be happening.  Try using the "Security Controls > Session Management" to kill the AuthSession. It shouldn't be possible to login once removed. You might find you have spawned additional separate sessions somehow.